# Android Studio - Share dependencies between multiple modules causes error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dependencies, android-module

I am implementing an `Android` app which have two modules. The `app` module uses `library` module. There is a dependency in `library`'s `build.gradle` file:

```
api "se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0"
```

and this library is used inside `app` module's `xml` files.

The `app's` `build.gradle` file includes `library` module:

```
implementation project(path: ':Library', configuration: 'default')
```

The problem now is that when I try to run on a device, I always see this error:

```
Android resource linking failed
error: attribute hasStickyHeaders not found.
error: attribute isDrawingListUnderStickyHeader not found.
error: failed linking file resources.
```

This is the library I am using:
https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Answer (score 0):

Add the gradle dependency like it instructs on github:

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:x.x.x'
    }
```